# class org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException No converter for [class java.lang.Boolean] with preset Content-Type 'null'

Tags: java, spring-boot

class org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException  No converter for [class java.lang.Boolean] with preset Content-Type 'null'

My Controller has a method that returns a Boolean type. Since there are some client services that require it to return the response as a "text/plain".

```
@RequestMapping(value="/test",method=RequestMethod.POST,produces= "text/plain")
public Boolean test() {
 return <boolean value>
}
```

When I use this it throws the below error
class org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException  No converter for [class java.lang.Boolean] with preset Content-Type 'null'

Answer (score 0):

While hitting the request try adding the `Accept` header in `curl` or `Postman`!

(Since you're returning a Boolean, use `toString()` to convert boolean to string before returning response)

`Accept: text/plain`

Comment: Thank you for the response. But I want the response type to be Boolean only. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes but in the response I believe it would be String or text only ! You may then parse it to Boolean if you are reading in another language !